# the sum of 1 + a + a^2 + _ _ _ + a^n

Tags: c++

here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int s = 1, i, n, m;
    double a;
    cin >> a >> n;
    while (n <= 0)
    {
        cin >> n;
    }
    m = a;
    for (i = 1; i <= n; i++)
    {
        s += m;
        m *= a;
    }
    cout << s << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

here was the start data:
Given a real number a and a natural n, calculate the sum 1 + a + a^2 + _ _ _ + a^n, without using the formula for the sum of a geometric progression. The running time of the program must be proportional to n.

Input data Enter 2 numbers - a and n.

Output It is necessary to display the value of the sum.
The checking program considers my code not full. Please explain where is the problem?

Comment: `m` is `int`, but `a` is `double`.

Comment: @JaMiT my bad..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`m *= a;`. `m` is an `int` type, while `a` is a `double` type

```cpp
#include <iostream>
// using namespace std; is bad, so don't use it

int main()
{
    // there's no need to declare a variable but leave it uninitialized.
    double a{};
    int n{};

    std::cin >> a;
    while (n <= 0)
    {
        std::cin >> n;
        std::cin.clear(); 
        std::cin.ignore(100, '\n');
    }

    double m{a}; 
    double s{1.0} 
    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) // declare i in the loop scope
    {
        s += m;
        m *= a;
    }                            
    std::cout << s << '\n'; // use newline character instead of std::endl
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: OP asked for the `a` value to be a real number (a `double`), not an integer. So must be `m` and `s`.

Answer (score 0):

You are using an infinite loop to read the value of n.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
int s = 1, i, n, m;
double a;
cin >> a >> n;
// The below code was causing an endless loop
// while (n <= 0)
// {
//     cin >> n;
// }
m = a;
for (i = 1; i <= n; i++)
{
    s += m;
    m *= a;
}
cout << s << endl;
return 0;
}
```

Commenting/removing the part of the code provides the result for the program.